# Cannot build gst-plugins-bad1.5 for Kurento compile error

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

I am trying to build gst-plugins-bad for Kurento project.
I have downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/Kurento/gst-plugins-bad) but while building I have following error:

```
usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(stack_chk_fail_local.oS): In function `__stack_chk_fail_local':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [libgstmodplug.la] Error 1
```

As I saw in google it's possible to workaround this problem by entering `-fno-stack-protector` while linking. But how can I do it? Or is there another way to build the plugins?

Thanks.

Comment: One idea would be to add the option to your `CFLAGS` environment variable.

Comment: I tried - didn't work (